# ASP.NET-JS-Razor : HowTo call OnBlur function from a htmlhelper

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

First off: Happy Newyear!

I'm trying to make a simple restaurant cash register. There is a list of dishes with the price, an inputfield for the amount ordered and a field where the subtotal of that line should be calculated.

I allready tried many approaches but i'm not getting there.. Now i got bits an pieces of different solution and im getting more confused.

Create.cshtml :

```
 <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.details)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Prijs (€)")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Aantal")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("SubTotaal")
            </th>
        </tr>

        @for(var i = 0; i < Model.details.Count; ++i) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.details[i].omschrijving)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.details[i].prijs, new { id = "txtPrijs" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.details[i].aantal, new { id = "txtAantal" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.details[i].subTotaal, new {id = "txtSubTotaal"}) 
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

So here are the 3 rows we need. Prijs * aantal = subtotaal
When someone enters the amount - the subtotal should be calculated on the fly.

> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.details[i].prijs, new { >id = "txtPrijs" })
>                      
>                     
>                          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.details[i].aantal, new { >id = "txtAantal" })
>                      
>                      
>                          @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.details[i].subTotaal, >new {id = "txtSubTotaal"})

Here is the Javascript that should do the calculating

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#txtAantal').blur(function () {
            var prijs = $.trim($("#txtPrijs").html());
            var aantal = $.trim($("#txtAantal").html());
            var tot = prijs * aantal;
            $("#txtSubTotaal").val(tot);

    });
});
```

**Now the questions:** 
- How can i call the script from the Displayfor? (onBlur) 
- Are there easier ways then this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Nope - JS isn't getting called. I think it has something to do with the naming that the Htmlhelper gives to txtaantal.

Comment: Right click on that element and inspect it in browser and see what `id` it has got?

Comment: id="details_16__aantal" but with different numbers each line.

Comment: so every time it has `id` with format `"details_changingnum_aantal"`? First and last word remains constant?

Comment: jes indeed. the new { id = txtAantal } does not do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you can use **[`endsWith`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)** selector of `jquery`, which selects elements which elements whose `id` ends with **`aantal`**.

For example:

```
$("input[id$='aantal']" ).on('blur',function(){
   //Similarly change for others
});
```

So now even though number changes this will fetch only that `input` whose `id` ends with **`aantal`**

---

**UPDATE**

**Option 1 - Use inline function call**

Add an inline `function` to trigger `onblur` event on your `textbox` as below:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.details[i].aantal, new { id = "txtAantal", onblur="calculate(this)" })
```

and write a `function` body

```
function calculate(control)
{
    var parent=$(control).closest('tr');
    var prijs = $.trim($(parent).find("label[id$='prijs']").val());
    var aantal = $.trim($(control).val());
    var tot = prijs * aantal;
    $(parent).find("label[id$='subTotaal']").val(tot);
}
```

> In the above function parent will fetch the closest tr for the control passed. The value for `prijis` will be fetched by searching the children of the parent referred and with `endswith` selector and same goes with subtotal.

**Option 2 - Assign a class to each `textbox` and add blur event to that class**

Add an attribute to `textbox` i.e. `class` and attach `blur` event on that as below:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.details[i].aantal, new { @class="aantal" })

$('.aantal').on('blur',function(){
    var parent=$(this).closest('tr'); //refer with this for current textbox
    var prijs = $.trim($(parent).find("label[id$='prijs']").val());
    var aantal = $.trim($(control).val());
    var tot = prijs * aantal;
    $(parent).find("label[id$='subTotaal']").val(tot);
});
```

Comment: I tried: 
$("input[id$='aantal']" ).on('blur',function(){   and    
$("input[id$='aantal']" ).blur(function () { 

Both don't get approached !

Comment: You see any console `errors`? Just execute `$("input[id$='aantal']")` in browser console and let me know what you get?

Comment: He returns all of the wanted field. So that works nicely. I don't get any errors. :/

Comment: Ok then try with one last this `$("input[id$='aantal']:visible").blur`

Comment: Or else you can have inline style like - `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.details[i].aantal, new { id = "txtAantal", onblur="calculate(this)" })` and then write the function as `function calculate(control){var aantalVal=$(control).val()}` and also fetch other values which exists in same tree by referring `control` element

Comment: $("input[id$='aantal']:visible").blur  results into::: Function( data, fn ) {
  return arguments.length > 0 ?
   this.on( name, null, data, fn ) :
   this.trigger( name );
 }

Comment: I'm gonna have to ask to treat me like an idiot.. :) -- Now the "control" is the value that is shown by "aantal" that you passed trough with "this". How can i ask the other value's trough the "control" variable?

Comment: That's why we are passing control.. Ok.. Let me edit my answer to give you more clarity on this.. :)

Comment: First off: Thank you so much for putting your time into this.. But none of the above seem to work. He just doens't jump into the script for some reason. He also shows "Prijs" as plain text between <td> so they are no labels.. If it's any easier, here is a wetrans link to the project. ( http://we.tl/R3Fl43ZATn  )

Comment: `DisplayFor` doesn't convert it into label? :o

Comment: Noes.. Just plane text :/

Comment: Wiered.. I could really help you if you could try to create a sample of the problem in **[`dotnetfiddle`](https://dotnetfiddle.net)**

Comment: I'm trying the oldfashion way with simple html bindings.. The helpers remove any possibility of adding a class or ID. I tried the fidle but he doesn't Save or give's me a link to share.. :( The wetransf link is a few comments above

Comment: Just login with your gmail and fork the fiddle.. You will get link generated in your addressbar..

Comment: Cool.. Instead of that dbset, try to keep some dummy hardcoded value which could be retrieved from DB and then update the link and give it back to me..

Answer (score 0):

When I first started out using MVC I also injected ViewModels straight from the controller into the view using razor. In your question you ask if there is a better way to solve your problem and I believe there is: [KnockoutJs](http://knockoutjs.com/).

You can import the package using nuget if you are using Visual Studio.

Knockout enables you to define a viewmodel in javascript which you can populate with the data coming from your ViewModel from the controller. Javascript allows you to program your calculations straight into the viewmodel (which is bound to the view using knockout).

No more complicated JQuery scripts needed. If you decide not to use this, I still recommend going through the examples to discover this amazing framework!

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I saw knockout passing by with all other possibilities. Looked far from what i allready got. If Guruprasad's solution is getting me no where, i'm going for this.

Comment: The time you will spend on learning how to work with knockout will repay itself in no time. Problems like you are having now will keep coming back. Knockout eliminates a lot of those out of the box and is - on top of it being awesome - also super extendable. Since I learned it, it is my go-to solution.

Comment: i tried wrapping my head around this example before but that didn't help me alot..  ( http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/adNuR/ )

Comment: This is a really good example for your problem. Try to get familiar with the basics of KO.